# Implementing Read typeclass where parsing strings includes "$"

Tags: haskell, linguistics

I've been playing with Haskell for about a month. For my first "real" Haskell project I'm writing a parts-of-speech tagger. As part of this project I have a type called `Tag` that represents a parts-of-speech tag, implemented as follows:

```
data Tag = CC | CD | DT | EX | FW | IN | JJ | JJR | JJS ...
```

The above is a long list of standardized parts-of-speech tags which I've intentionally truncated. However, in this standard set of tags there are two that end in a dollar sign ($): PRP$ and NNP$. Because I can't have type constructors with $ in their name, I've elected to rename them PRPS and NNPS.

This is all well and good, but I'd like to read tags from strings in a lexicon and convert them to my `Tag` type. Trying this fails:

```
instance Read Tag where
    readsPrec _ input =
        (\inp -> [((NNPS), rest) | ("NNP$", rest) <- lex inp]) input
```

The Haskell lexer chokes on the $. Any ideas how to pull this off?

Implementing Show was fairly straightforward. It would be great if there were some similar strategy for Read.

```
instance Show Tag where
    showsPrec _ NNPS = showString "NNP$"
    showsPrec _ PRPS = showString "PRP$"
    showsPrec _ tag  = shows tag
```

Comment: Pretty much the only time you should be writing your own `Show` and `Read` instances, instead of using the instances that get derived automatically, is if your data type hides its internal representation (like `Data.Set.Set` and such, which spit out a `fromList` call) or works with literals, e.g. an instance of `Num` spitting out an integer literal it corresponds to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're abusing `Read` here.

`Show` and `Read` are meant to print and parse valid Haskell values, to enable debugging, etc.  This doesn't always perfectly (e.g. if you import `Data.Map` qualified and then call `show` on a `Map` value, the call to `fromList` isn't qualified) but it's a valid starting point.

If you want to print or parse your values to match some specific format, then use a pretty-printing library for the former and an actual parsing library (e.g. uu-parsinglib, polyparse, parsec, etc.) for the latter.  They typically have much nicer support for parsing than `ReadS` (though `ReadP` in GHC isn't *too* bad).

Whilst you may argue that this isn't necessary, this is just a quick'n'dirty hack you're doing, quick'n'dirty hacks have a tendency to linger around... do yourself a favour and do it right the first time: it means there's less to re-write when you want to do it "properly" later on.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. And here I was thinking this was the proper way to do things, otherwise I wouldn't have bothered with a Read parser at all (the rows of the lexicon are nicely formatted and broken up using the standard `words` function)! Coming from OOP, I guess I'm still thinking of typeclasses as interfaces I must implement to get the behavior I need.

Comment: Specifically, `Read` and `Show` are intended to be a matching set of poor man's serialization/deserialization to and from `String`, with the additional expectation that the serialized form, if cut and paste into the original source file, would represent a value equivalent to the one `show` was applied to.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use the Haskell lexer then. The `read` functions use ParSec, which you can find an excellent introduction to in the Real World Haskell book.

Here's some code that seems to work,

```
import Text.Read
import Text.ParserCombinators.ReadP hiding (choice)
import Text.ParserCombinators.ReadPrec hiding (choice)

data Tag = CC | CD | DT | EX | FW | IN | JJ | JJR | JJS deriving (Show)

strValMap = map (\(x, y) -> lift $ string x >> return y)

instance Read Tag where
    readPrec = choice $ strValMap [
        ("CC", CC),
        ("CD", CD),
        ("JJ$", JJS)
        ]
```

just run it with

```
(read "JJ$") :: Tag
```

The code is pretty self explanatory. The `string x` parser monad matches `x`, and if it succeeds (doesn't throw an exception), then `y` is returned. We use `choice` to select among all of these. It will backtrack appropriately, so if you add a `CCC` constructor, then `CC` partially matching "CCC" will fail later, and it will backtrack to `CCC`. Of course, if you don't need this, then use the `<|>` combinator.

Comment: Thanks. This is pretty much exactly what I was trying to accomplish.

Comment: @gatoatigrado: actually, the `Read` functions do **not** use parsec: they have their own parser.