# Override show method for String/Char in Haskell

Tags: string, haskell, char, overriding, show

I have a question:
How can I override the show method for String or Char ?
Thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want to just define some other functions of type `Char -> String` or `String -> String`? Why do you want to override `show`?

Comment: I think you have to wrap it in a [new type](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Newtype) and define Show for that type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're wanting to do this, then you're doing it wrong.

For a more technical reason why, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7438587/implementing-read-typeclass-where-parsing-strings-includes/7438687#7438687) to a previous question.

You **really** should be using either your own `a -> String` functions (possibly via your own type-class) or use a pretty-printing library for more detailed outputs (some of which already have an inbuilt `Pretty` class).

Answer (score 8):

Since people seem to like my comment, here it is as an answer:

If you want to reimplement type classes on existing types, you can wrap them in a [`newtype`](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Newtype)-declared type. This allows you to define your own implementations, without any actual overhead at runtime (because `newtype` is isomorphic to the original type, there's no actual boxing done at runtime).

This might look something like this:

```
newtype MyChar = MyChar Char

instance Show MyChar where
  show (MyChar c) = "head \"" ++ c : "\""
```

You can use this by wrapping `Char`s with `MyChar`, like so:

```
print $ fmap MyChar "test"
```

This will print out

```
[head "t",head "e",head "s",head "t"]
```

Comment: You can also define showList, then lists of MyChar will have custom formatting too. In fact, this is why showing lists of characters ([Char]) behaves differently than showing other lists ([a]).